# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have an error with the help command, the error is

```
<rejected> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
      at /home/runner/mUdollar1cB0t/commands/help.js:16:55
```

```
client.commands.forEach(cmd => {
  let cmdinfo = cmd.info
  allcmds+="`" + client.config.prefix + cmdinfo.name+" " + cmdinfo.usage+"` ~ " + cmdinfo.description+"\n"
})
```

is the code I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: The problem is `cmd.info` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `cmdinfo` is undefined, you need to verify if you have some data in `cmd.info` to proceed with your code.